# Magento 2 Big numbers in backlog for indexer

Tags: magento2, reindex

When I run `php bin/magento indexer:status` I got the following result.

```
Title                                | Status           | Update On | Schedule Status             | Schedule Updated    |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| Aheadworks One Step Checkout Reports | Reindex required | Schedule  | idle (28 in backlog)        | 2018-10-09 05:20:56 |
| Catalog Product Rule                 | Ready            | Schedule  | working (264312 in backlog) | 2018-10-05 15:57:32 |
| Catalog Rule Product                 | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)         | 2018-10-09 08:51:18 |
| Catalog Search                       | Reindex required | Schedule  | suspended (3491 in backlog) | 2018-10-05 15:57:28 |
| Category Flat Data                   | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)         | 2018-10-09 08:38:30 |
| Category Products                    | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)         | 2018-10-09 08:42:36 |
| Customer Grid                        | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)         | 2018-10-09 08:36:39 |
| Design Config Grid                   | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)         | 2018-10-09 08:36:18 |
| Product Categories                   | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (4413 in backlog)      | 2018-10-05 15:57:25 |
| Product EAV                          | Processing       | Schedule  | suspended (1 in backlog)    | 2018-10-09 08:51:18 |
| Product Flat Data                    | Ready            | Schedule  | idle (1 in backlog)         | 2018-10-09 08:38:24 |
| Product Price                        | Reindex required | Schedule  | suspended (2640 in backlog) | 2018-10-05 15:57:30 |
| Stock                                | Reindex required | Schedule  | suspended (1060 in backlog) | 2018-10-05 15:57:26
```

Notice the **numbers** in **backlog** under the column *Schedule Status*

Why it says **264312** in backlog for the **Catalog Product Rule**?  I have ran reindexing many times, but numbers in backlog get only bigger and bigger.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below command to fix the above issue:

```
bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and then run your indexing command.

Comment: I'm trying this now. I'll write feedback when reindexing is done. efter indexer:reset, it  takes longer time to reindex? Catalog Product Rule has been running for more than 1 hour now. It was quicker before.

Comment: for your info. indexer:reset didn't fix the problem.

Comment: not working :(
any other ideas?